# Setting a baseline for a project pragmatically in workfront

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I've tried the following call as a put:
/api/project?id=xxxx&autoBaselineRecurOn=1&autoBaselineRecurrenceType=D&enableAutoBaselines=true&apiKey=xxxx
and I get a response with a dataset; however, I don't see the baseline in the project itself.  I don't get a baseline id back in the call, so I can't call the baseline api.  How do I setup up a daily (or weekly) baseline for a project via the api?  I queried the project, and I get a null in the nextAutoBaselineDate field.

Comment: I probably can't answer this, but just saying anyway: this is a poorly phrased question. "baseline" - what are you talking about? Is this a term from a product called workfront? You need to provide context for us to help you. Looking at the body it seems as you are trying to call some kind of HTTP API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The tags indicate that I'm talking about the attask api.  Within the api (and the attask also known as workfront application) there is the notion of creating a baseline for a project.  The HTTP snippet is the call that I'm making to setup the baseline of the project.  While the question may be unclear, I'm trying to understand why the call doesn't appear to actually create the project baseline.  Perhaps that makes my question clearer.

Comment: It absolutely does :)

Comment: Thanks again.  I modified the tags to be a bit clearer in my quest for an answer.